# random position of divs and hover function

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, hover

I've found this code to create some div randomly :

```
(function makeDiv(){
   var divsize = ((Math.random()*100) + 50).toFixed();
   var color = '#'+ Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16);
   $newdiv = $('<div/>').addClass("destruct").css({
       'width':divsize+'px',
       'height':divsize+'px',
       'background-color': color
   });

   var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width() - divsize)).toFixed();
   var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() - divsize)).toFixed();

   $newdiv.css({
       'position':'absolute',
       'left':posx+'px',
       'top':posy+'px',
       'display':'none'
   }).appendTo( 'body' ).fadeIn(500, function(){
      makeDiv(); 
   }); 
})();
```

But I want the div turn to black on hover, one by one.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.destruct').hover( function(){
    $('.destruct', this).css({background: '#000'});
   });
});
```

But it doesn't work...

Here is a http://jsfiddle.net/q6L7C/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q6L7C/5/)

Its because your div's are dynamically generated, try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).on('mouseover', '.destruct', function(){
      $(this).css({background: '#000'});
   });
});
```

If you are on older versions of jquery, (>1.7), Use:

```
$(".destruct").live("mouseover", function(){
    $(this).css({background: '#000'});
});
```

Comment: Do you want to revert back to the real color on mouseout?

Comment: No need, but it can be useful for others maybe. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to go about doing this.  One is event delegation:

http://jsfiddle.net/q6L7C/3/

This changes the binding to:

```
$(document).on('hover', '.destruct', function(){
   $(this).css({background: '#000'});
});
```

...but I would try to use a more specific selector than `document`.

Another solution would be to bind the `hover` (or `mouseover` in this case, as it should be sufficient) callback to each of the divs individually as they get created, but that results in potentially a lot of separate event bindings.

Comment: Just my 2ct: The use of "hover" is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8 in favor of "mouseenter mouseleave"

Comment: @devnull69 The use of `.hover`, the use of an event named `hover`, or both?

Comment: Only the "hover" as a shorthand of "mouseenter mouseleave" because you can only bind one handler to both with this method. `.hover()` has not been deprecated (yet)

Comment: @devnull69 well I do imply in my answer that `mouseover` should be used (although `mouseenter` would work the same in this case).

Answer (score 1):

You can bind `.mouseenter()` when you create divs or you can bind `.mouseenter()` to document (event delegation) as other answers pointed out. I will go with first method. [Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/q6L7C/13/)

```
(function makeDiv(){
    var divsize = ((Math.random()*100) + 50).toFixed();
    var color = '#'+ Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16);
    $newdiv = $('<div/>').addClass("destruct").css({
        'width':divsize+'px',
        'height':divsize+'px',
        'background-color': color
    })
    // Magic happens here!
    .mouseenter(function(){
      $(this).css({background: '#000'});
    });

    var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width() - divsize)).toFixed();
    var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() - divsize)).toFixed();

    $newdiv.css({
        'position':'absolute',
        'left':posx+'px',
        'top':posy+'px',
        'display':'none'
    }).appendTo( 'body' ).fadeIn(500, function(){
       makeDiv();
    });
})();
```